# Iterate through getNamespace response

Tags: javascript, node.js, kubernetes

I am trying to get a list of namespaces in a cluster with the @kubernets/client-node
I want to be able to access the name of each namespace and console log it out or even save it to a new array and print the array

this is my code for getting the namespaces and I thought this loop would work

```
       k8sApi.listNamespace().then((res) => {
       for(let i = 0; i<res.length; i++) {
           console.log(res.body.items.metadata[0].name);
       }
       console.log(res.body);
   }, error => {
        console.log("Rejected promise " + JSON.stringify(error));
    });
```

it just prints out the whole response body.

```
2021-05-03T21:35:26.089Z    bc91c93c-21f3-47ba-8403-78a5a061e508    INFO    V1NamespaceList {
  apiVersion: 'v1',
  items: [
    V1Namespace {
      apiVersion: undefined,
      kind: undefined,
      metadata: [V1ObjectMeta],
      spec: [V1NamespaceSpec],
      status: [V1NamespaceStatus]
    },
    V1Namespace {
      apiVersion: undefined,
      kind: undefined,
      metadata: [V1ObjectMeta],
      spec: [V1NamespaceSpec],
      status: [V1NamespaceStatus]
    },
    V1Namespace {
      apiVersion: undefined,
      kind: undefined,
      metadata: [V1ObjectMeta],
      spec: [V1NamespaceSpec],
      status: [V1NamespaceStatus]
    },
    V1Namespace {
      apiVersion: undefined,
      kind: undefined,
      metadata: [V1ObjectMeta],
      spec: [V1NamespaceSpec],
      status: [V1NamespaceStatus]
    },
    V1Namespace {
      apiVersion: undefined,
      kind: undefined,
      metadata: [V1ObjectMeta],
      spec: [V1NamespaceSpec],
      status: [V1NamespaceStatus]
    }
  ],
  kind: 'NamespaceList',
  metadata: V1ListMeta {
    _continue: undefined,
    resourceVersion: '331874',
    selfLink: '/api/v1/namespaces'
  }
```

How can I get into the body to where the namespace is?

Comment: Do you need to compare to `res.body.items.length` in the loop header; or call `res.body.items.forEach(item => { ... })`?

Comment: @David Maze I thought I could access the data in the metadata array that way but I guess I am using my loop incorrectly, really all I want to do to is get the name field from the metadata so I can see the name of each namespace. I'm guessing the name of the namespace is in metadata: [V1ObjectMeta]? I'm just shooting in the dark here I am not fully sure what the correct structure of the object being returned by listNamespace